# Can I test a XLR microphone with a DMM?

Tags: audio, microphone

I have a microphone with a XLR output and a XLR to PL cable. I don't get from it any signal on my PC. Can I test with a DMM the microphone and the cable  in order to locate the problem?

Comment: what sort of microphone is it?

Comment: @Jasen 
It's a Pyle PDMIC58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a moving coil dynamic. microphone so a resistance mesurement between the signal pins (pins 2 and 3) should show a few hundered ohms. the microphone may emit a clicking sound during the measurement this is normal.

measurement from pin 1 should show no connection to the other pins.

the cable on the on the other hand should be taking a few miliamperes from the microphone socket, (you'll need to make up a an adaptor so you can measure the current going into the microphone cable also measure the voltage on the plug it shopuld be about 1 to 4 volts.

the other test is to put a signal on the XLR input end of the cable, it only need to be a few millivolts, you could use bare loudspeaker driver and shout into it - you should get some audio outof the cable - so run some software tha graphs what it hears on the microphone socket.

As @PeterBennet prompts me. the microphone cable could be just a plain cable with no in-built circuitry. if that's the case it's not going to work with a direct connection to the PC.

Comment: The microphone or cable SHOULD NOT draw any current from the microphone socket.  It does not use phantom power.

Comment: @PeterBennett  The phantom power from a MIC socket will often be present with a dynamic microphone even if it is not needed unless a decoupling capacitor is present or a smart MIC socket switches off power when loaded more than a FET microphone would draw.

Comment: @PeterBennett I'm expecting a pre-amp run from the PC's microphone socket bias power. is that's not part of the cable it's not going to work with a PC,

Comment: @Jasen  I tested the mic as you described and it's Ok. I didn't understand the last remark (the  in-built circuitry) but I saw people claim that it worked on their PC. As for testing the cable - do you mean shouting into a speaker and connecting it's cables to - to which pins exactly?

Comment: pins 2 and three...

Comment: Meanwhile I've tested the cable wit ha DMM. Pins 1,2 are connected to the mono PL body, pin 1 is connected to the head (but with about 2 ohm). Does this mean anything?

Comment: If you turn the gain and boost right up it might work. but I think you'll need a pre-amplifier to make it work.